# Not empty value a input after add new input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input in example and after add new input remove(or empty) values they now want not remove value a input, how is it?

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/3SmyE/

my try:

```
$clone.find('input').not(':has(name="family_un[]")').val('');
```

Full js code:

```
$(function () {
    $('a.add_input').live('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();       
        var $this = $(this),
            $div = $this.closest('.add_units'),
            $clone = $div.clone().hide().insertAfter($div).fadeIn('slow');
        $clone.find('.adda').not(':has(.remove_input)').append('<div class="mediumCell"><a href="" class="remove_input"></a></div>');
        $clone.find('input').not(':has(name="family_un[]")').val('');
        $this.remove();
        console.log($('.add_units:last input:checkbox').prop('name'));
    });   
});
```

Comment: Can you try to rewrite that first sentence? It's very difficult to understand what the problem is, and I didn't see anything obviously wrong with your demo.

Comment: Serious awful question asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*After applying my knowledge of cryptography, I've found the solution to your question.*
**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3SmyE/1/**

Your current code:

```
$clone.find('input').not(':has(name="family_un[]")').val('');
```

Fixed code:

```
$clone.find('input').not('[name="family_un[]"]').val('');
```

The `:has()` pseudo-selector which selects **child elements** of the preceding selector. To select attributes, you have to suround the attribute by square bracelets, in the following format:
`[attribute="value"]`.

Comment: +1 for your knowledge of cryptography, and for demonstrating that square brackets don't need to be escaped in selectors anymore.